# compare jquery val VS array value

Tags: jquery

I need to compare 2 values. One value comes from input box, the other one is in an array.

```
    var caja = $("#txtRespuesta").val();
    alert("Comprueba respuesta: " + caja);
    $("#puntos").text(puntos); 
    var obj2String = (arregloDePhp[indiceArregloPhp]).toString();
    // if (res2.equals(obj2String.toString())){ //complains that object has no method .equals
     if (caja==obj2String){ 
    puntos+=1; 
    };
    console.log ("comparing: "+caja+" y "+obj2String);//actually this shows both words are the same
    indiceArregloPhp+=1;
```

Can't find what is it, please point me out in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `caja===obj2String`
additionaly it would be better if you would trim the value before comparing using $.trim().

Comment: hi Zahid, I added the extra = sign and trimmed the values, still it isn't working. 1st time it returns false, as puntos isn't increased. second time, does get increased and third time (and onwards)  no increase again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.inArray()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
$.inArray(valueFromInput, yourArray) // returns the index or -1 if not found
```